# Moongoose Socket closed in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am facing moongoose scoket cloased issue. After starting server within few hours i am getting this issue. If i send request to server i am getting socket closed error and after sometime i m getting socket hung up error.
MY CODE:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
// here i am connecting mongo db with particular api
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vs-court-agent')

var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost/db-agent'

var connectWithRetry = function() {
  return mongoose.connect(mongoUrl, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to mongo on startup - retrying in 5 sec', err);
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    }
  });
};
connectWithRetry();

setInterval(function(){
  if(!mongoose.connection.readyState){
    console.log("mongo trying to reconnect")
    connectWithRetry()
  }
},1000)
```

route code:

```
app.post('/agent', function(req,res){
console.log(req.body)
// var newagent = new agent(req.body)
if(req.body.agentName && req.body.agentNo && req.body.agentType && req.body.agentYear){
  Agent.findOne({ agentName: req.body.agentName, agentNo: req.body.agentNo, agentType: req.body.agentType, agentYear: req.body.agentYear }, function(err, result){
        if(err){
          return res.json({info: "Unable to get data", error:err})
        }
        if(result){
          // return res.json({data: result})
          // _.merge(result, req.body)
          result.agentDetails = req.body.agentDetails
          result.save(function(error){
            if(error){
              return res.json({info: "Error while updating data", error: err})
            }
            return res.json({info: "agent updated Successfully"})
          })
        }else{
          var newAgent = new Agent(req.body, false)
          newAgent.save(function(err){
            if(err){
             return res.json({info: "Unable to create agent", error:err})
            };
            return res.json({info: 'agent Created Successfully'})
          })
        }
  })
}else{
  return res.json({info: 'agentNo,agentName,agentType,agentYear are mandatory'})
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mongo connect call pass the option for the keepAlive flag. It will re-establish the connection when TCP socket timer reaches to the zero. 
var mongoOptions = {socketOptions: {keepAlive: 1}};
mongoose.connect( YOUR_URI, mongoOptions );`

see the link given below : 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html